# I can not access to the Typescript Class with "this" after ngClick

Tags: angular, typescript, onclick, click

I'm trying to acces to my class after a (click) on the template in Angular2+, but when I write console.log(this) I am getting the DOM object.

Let me show you my code:

```
deleteClient(row: Client, event: any): void
{

  console.log(this);
  console.log(event);
  console.log(this.notificationService);

  this.notificationService.open(...);

}

/* Aditional columns for clients. */
addAditionalColumns(): SpeerdListAdditionalColumn[]{

  let addAditionalColumns = [{
      label: "Delete",
      icon: "far fa-trash-alt",
      onclick: this.deleteClient,
      textAlign: 'center'
  }];

  return addAditionalColumns;
}
```

This is my template; list.tpl. I do a NgFor with the return off addAditionalColumns().

```
<!-- Additional columns -->
<ng-container *ngFor="let additionalColumn of additionalColumns" [cdkColumnDef]="additionalColumn.label">
       <!-- Head columns -->
       <cdk-header-cell *cdkHeaderCellDef [ngStyle]="{'text-align': additionalColumn.textAlign}">
               {{additionalColumn.label}} 
       </cdk-header-cell>
       <!-- Body columns -->
       <cdk-cell *cdkCellDef="let row" [ngStyle]="{'text-align': additionalColumn.textAlign}"> 
              <i (click)="$event.stopPropagation(); additionalColumn.onclick(row, $event);" class="{{additionalColumn.icon}}"></i> 
       </cdk-cell>
</ng-container>
```

What I am getting with the console.log(this) in deleteClient function is:

```
 {label: "Borrar", icon: "far fa-trash-alt", onclick: ƒ, textAlign: "center"}
```

And I need the ComponentClass instance. How can I access to class instance?

Code:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-votuyc?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Did you try this - `onclick: this.deleteClient.bind(this)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the shorthand arrow function to do this for defining your method. Something like:

```
deleteClient = (row: Client, event: any): void => { 
    //this now refers to the component instance
}
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions for more on that operator

Comment: Now I get  "_v.parent.context.$implicit.onclick is not a function", but in a simple application it works. Thanks I am going to see what is happening.

Comment: I reproduce the error here  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-votuyc?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: That error is telling you that your component doesn't have a method "onclick" defined. The name of your method in your example is "deleteClient". You could either adjust your method definition to be named "onclick" to match what's in your template, or adjust your template to reference to call the "deleteClient" method.